# retrieve data from hbase using prefix string

Tags: filter, hbase

I am using hbase 0.98.4

I want to retrieve data from hbase table by using scanner with java api where my 
startRow :  username_uniqueId
stopRow is : username_uniqueId* so here there can be anything appended

I set these param to scan object but it is not fetching data from hbase table. 
Basically i want to fetch all records which starts with some specific string.

For this i can use prefix filter but i came to know it kills hbase performance as it scan whole hbase table. So i am avoiding it.

Can anyone have a better solution apart from using prefix filter?